# How Can I Get Cygwin To Forget Old Computer Name After It is Changed?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I need help with a very bad Cygwin problem I can’t find that anyone ever previously had.

[Minor side question: It would help a lot to know for sure what everyone means when they say cygwin HOME directory.  /home, or /home/user?]

Major problem is I gave a new Dell PC (Window 10) a Computer Name with two spaces and an apostrophe.

Windows accepted it, even though it’s not supposed to.  It even assigned it as my User Name.

The spaces obviously cause havoc with cygwin.  And I’m beginning to fear there is no way to fix that.

Even though I changed the Computer Name Geo2, and its only user Geo2 as well, cygwin keeps finding the old dumb name and reusing it, which of course causes many problems.

[Ok. For everyone’s amusement it was: “Ann’s Little Hun”. It seemed harmless, because I read it can be changed later.]

More specifically, after I change the Computer Name, scrubbed the old install and reinstalled cygwin:

This is where it’s installed:

```
C:\ProgramFilesGeo\CygwinBinHome\
  bin    
  dev
  etc
  home\Ann's Little Hun
  ... 
  Var
  Cygwin.bat
  Cygwin.ico
  Cygwin-Terminal.ico
```

But this is the terminal window output I get when I first opened cygwin after thinking I changed the computer name.

```
Copying skeleton files.
These files are for the users to personalise their cygwin experience.

They will never be overwritten nor automatically updated.

'./.bashrc' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.bashrc"
'./.bash_profile' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.bash_profile"
'./.inputrc' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.inputrc"
'./.profile' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.profile"

Ann's Little Hun@Geo2 ~
$ cd /home

Ann's Little Hun@Geo2 /home
$ dir
Ann's\ Little\ Hun
```

Note 1: Cygwin is still finding the name I first gave the computer somewhere.

Note 2: That causes it to think home has three subdirectories.

Here’s a list of all the info I put below:

1 The steps I used to change the computer’s name

2 The steps I used to totally remove the first installation, i.e. when the computer had the old name.

3 The selections I used to reinstall cygwin after I changed the Computer and User Names.

**Change Computer name:**

--- I used sysdm.cpl to rename it Geo2. Restarted.

--- Confirmed using Windows Settings System About.  It now says Geo2.

--- I also used Windows Settings Accounts.  The only user is now Geo2.

**To Remove prior installations:**

--- Made sure hidden files were visible, i.e. all the .bash files

--- Delete cygwin home directory, i.e. directory that has bin and the rest.

--- Deleted the directory where downloaded packages were saved in a directory with a name something like: http%3a%2f%2fwww.pirbot.com%2fmirrors%2fcygwin%2f

--- Deleted log files created from the first install.

--- Deleted setup-x86_64.exe

--- Delete the HOME Environmental Variable.

--- For Registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Cygwin/Installations
     Left subkey: (Default) set to (value not set)
     Deleted the subkey created by the first install:  99fb8763c5c8ea38

--- For Registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /SOFTWARE/Cygwin/Installations
     Did same thing as above.
--- For Registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE /SOFTWARE/Cygwin/setup
     Left subkey: (Default) set to (value not set)
     Left subkey: rootdir in place, but deleted it’s value, i.e. left the value blank.

--- Unpined shortcut from taskbar.

--- Deleted desktop shortcut.

--- Removed Cygwin from windows menu app list.

**Final Re-installation:**

--- Created a new directory cygwin home.  Used an entirely different name than first install.

--- Downloaded a new copy of setup-x86_64.exe.

--- Executed it as follows:

**Choose a Download Source:**  Clicked on Install from internet.

**Select Root Install Directory:** I Used C:\CygwinBinHome.

**Install For:** Selected All Users

**Select Local Package Directory:**  I used C:\Downloads\Cygwin.

**Select Your Internet Connection:**  Select Direct Connection.

**Choose A Download Site:**  I used ftp ://ftp.atlib.gatech.edu

**Select Packages:**    I entered openssh in the Search Text Box
Then clicked to change the three that showed up to “install”

**Resolving Dependencies:** Accepted all listed.

---

At that point I swore there was no way Cygwin could reuse the old dumb name.
I was wrong.  See terminal output above.

I am obviously missing something important.

Is it possible I can never get rid of the dumb name?

Laughter and ridicule is ok.  It really was dumb.

But help or a new direction would be greatly appreciated as well.
glb

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

PS: For those who follow. I'm putting notes here so I can use the "code" format that doesn't work in the notes section.

First help below suggested using uname -n and mkpasswed -c. The result confirmed that Cygwin is still seeing my computer with the original dumb name:

```
Ann's Little Hun@Geo2 ~
$ uname -n
Geo2

Ann's Little Hun@Geo2 ~
$ mkpasswd -c
Ann's Little Hun:*:197609:197121:U-GEO2\Ann's Little Hun,S-1-5-21-1992435346-218                                                              5703021-1381555857-1001:/home/Ann's Little Hun:/bin/bash
```

Comment: I suspect Windows is providing the name to Cygwin and just using the new name as Alias for the original one used internally. Check with `uname -n` and with `mkpasswd -c` the machine name as Cygwin sees it

Comment: Thank you.  You are right.  Cygwin is still seeing my computer by its old name. (I put terminal output above in main question). But I can't find anything else mentioned anywhere related to Cygwin that I could have removed after the first awful installation, so I have no idea where Cygwin is finding the old name.  Any suggestion of anywhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to matzeri ... sort of ... I ended up with a MS technician who finally gave up and said MS couldn't fix the problem.  I.e. the only solution to killing the zombie User who did not exit but who irreversibly owned the directory and all its files was to reset my new computer to factory settings.  AND LOSE everything installed!

Moral:  If you ever intend to use Cygwin or any Linux based programs on a PC ... DO NOT GET CUTE AND GIVE YOUR MACHINE A NAME WITH ANY SPACES IN IT.

At least that's what seemed to set this problem in motion ... but given not even a MS technitician had any idea of how to fix it ... there's no way to ever tell for sure.

Sure hope someone makes it possible to run Word, Excel and Outlook on Linux some day.

geo

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem as you post. I used custom HOME directory, which set from when system boot by batch script.
In my case, I add ending-space by mistake. "set HOME=D:\OneDrive_MyProgram\HOME "
therefore, Cygwin always try to make this directory whenever I delete it.
In this case, below kinds of log is printed, because of making new HOME directory

`

```
  './.bashrc' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.bashrc"
  './.bash_profile' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.bash_profile"
  './.inputrc' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.inputrc"
  './.profile' -> "/home/Ann's Little Hun//.profile"
```

`

Please refer it